# Change clang selected gcc installation

Tags: compiling, gcc, clang

I'm working on a Ubuntu 16.04 system. First I run `sudo apt install gcc clang gcc-multilib g++-multilib` but then I realised that I need the `gcc version 4.9` to compile my code, so I delete the `5.4` :

```
sudo apt remove gcc g++ gcc-multilib g++-multlib
```

After that I reinstalled the `4.9` versions:

```
sudo apt install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9 gcc-4.9-multilib g++-4.9-multilib
```

To compile my program I use `cc` and after trying to compile it again it failed, so I executed `cc -v` to see what's happening and here is the output.

```
$ cc -v
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.3
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.3
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.0.0
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Candidate multilib: x32;@mx32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

Is there any way to properly make clang select the `4.9` as a selected GCC installation?

Thanks